# How to simplify text comparison for big data-set where text meaning is same but not exact - deduplicate text data

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, nlp, duplicates, cosine-similarity

I have text data set (different menu items like chocolate, cake, coke etc) of around 1.8 million records which belongs to 6 different categories (category A, B, C, D, E, F). one of the category has around 700k records. Most of the menu items are mixed up in multiple categories to which they doesn't belong to, for example: cake belongs to category 'A' but it is found in category 'B' & 'C' as well.

I want to identify those misclassified items and report to a personnel but the challenge is the item name is not always correct because it is totally human typed text. For example: Chocolate might be updated as hot chclt, sweet choklate, chocolat etc. There can also be items like chocolate cake ;)

so to handle this, I tried a simple method using cosine similarity to compare category-wise and identify those anomalies but it takes alot of time since I am comparing each items to 1.8 million records (Sample code is as shown below). Can anyone suggest a better way to deal with this problem?

```
#Function
from nltk.corpus import stopwords 
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize 

def cos_similarity(a,b):
    X =a
    Y =b

    # tokenization 
    X_list = word_tokenize(X)  
    Y_list = word_tokenize(Y) 

    # sw contains the list of stopwords 
    sw = stopwords.words('english')  
    l1 =[];l2 =[] 

    # remove stop words from the string 
    X_set = {w for w in X_list if not w in sw}  
    Y_set = {w for w in Y_list if not w in sw} 

    # form a set containing keywords of both strings  
    rvector = X_set.union(Y_set)  
    for w in rvector: 
        if w in X_set: l1.append(1) # create a vector 
        else: l1.append(0) 
        if w in Y_set: l2.append(1) 
        else: l2.append(0) 
    c = 0

    # cosine formula  
    for i in range(len(rvector)): 
            c+= l1[i]*l2[i] 
    if float((sum(l1)*sum(l2))**0.5)>0:
        cosine = c / float((sum(l1)*sum(l2))**0.5) 
    else:
        cosine = 0
    return cosine

#Base code
cos_sim_list = []
for i in category_B.index:
    ln_cosdegree = 0
    ln_degsem = []
    for j in category_A.index:
        ln_j = str(category_A['item_name'][j])
        ln_i = str(category_B['item_name'][i])
        degreeOfSimilarity = cos_similarity(ln_j,ln_i)
        if degreeOfSimilarity>0.5:
            cos_sim_list.append([ln_j,ln_i,degreeOfSimilarity])
```

Consider text is already cleaned

Comment: I would be clearer if you show a full example (e.g. input -> output format)

Comment: Hi James, I figured out a way to deal with this problem using KNeighbors and cosine similarity and it is working for my usecase. Though I am still comparing category by category, it is still effective for me. Please do let me know if you can find any better idea to handle this problem

Answer (score 0):

I used KNeighbor and cosine similarity to solve this case. Though I am running the code multiple times to compare category by category; still it is effective because of lesser number of categories. Please suggest me if any better solution is available

[image]

[image]

```
cat_A_clean = category_A['item_name'].unique()

print('Vecorizing the data - this could take a few minutes for large datasets...')
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=1, analyzer=ngrams, lowercase=False)
tfidf = vectorizer.fit_transform(cat_A_clean)
print('Vecorizing completed...')

from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors
nbrs = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=1, n_jobs=-1).fit(tfidf)

unique_B = set(category_B['item_name'].values) 

def getNearestN(query):
    queryTFIDF_ = vectorizer.transform(query)
    distances, indices = nbrs.kneighbors(queryTFIDF_)
    return distances, indices

import time
t1 = time.time()
print('getting nearest n...')
distances, indices = getNearestN(unique_B)
t = time.time()-t1
print("COMPLETED IN:", t)

unique_B = list(unique_B) 
print('finding matches...')
matches = []
for i,j in enumerate(indices):
    temp = [round(distances[i][0],2), cat_A_clean['item_name'].values[j],unique_B[i]]
    matches.append(temp)

print('Building data frame...')  
matches = pd.DataFrame(matches, columns=['Match confidence (lower is better)','ITEM_A','ITEM_B'])
print('Done') 

def clean_string(text):
        text = str(text)
        text = text.lower()
        return(text)
def cosine_sim_vectors(vec1,vec2):
    vec1 = vec1.reshape(1,-1)
    vec2 = vec2.reshape(1,-1)
    return cosine_similarity(vec1,vec2)[0][0]

def cos_similarity(sentences):
    cleaned = list(map(clean_string,sentences))
    print(cleaned)
    vectorizer = CountVectorizer().fit_transform(cleaned)
    vectors = vectorizer.toarray()
    print(vectors) 
    return(cosine_sim_vectors(vectors[0],vectors[1]))

cos_sim_list =[]
for ind in matches.index:
    a = matches['Match confidence (lower is better)'][ind]
    b = matches['ITEM_A'][ind]
    c = matches['ITEM_B'][ind]
    degreeOfSimilarity = cos_similarity([b,c])
    cos_sim_list.append([a,b,c,degreeOfSimilarity])
```